# Solr Split Text Field at fixed length and Store in Multiple CopyFields

Tags: solr

All
We are storing shape data in Solr as RPT datatype, but we also need to perform custom function using the data. But to do that we need docValues so we are copying the data to a copyfield. With lucene docValues have 32K limit. So we need to split the data at length 32000 chars and store them in 3 copy fields. Copy field is better for other reasons.

How can I achieve this without writing some custom updateRequest code.. ? Is there a way to do this using tokenizer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate on copyField, but not grab the middle part.

Instead, you could use [UpdateRequestProcessors](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/) and combine a couple of CloneField and RegexReplace processors to get what you want.